# Please confirm: SYSDATETIME() is slower than GETDATE() in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns several thousand records, joined across several tables. In the WHERE clause, a date is checked to be no more than two months in the past. At first, the query had this date boundary set up as a variable and the WHERE used that.

```
DECLARE @startdate as DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, SYSDATETIME())

select [....]
where dateinquestion >= @startdate
```

This runs just fine (returns the result expected in under 4 seconds), but I wanted to get rid of the variable declaration and move the assignment into the WHERE clause itself:

```
select [....]
where dateinquestion >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, SYSDATETIME())
```

This runs for over a minute and eats all CPU. I killed the query to stop pushing the server, no results were given. Changing to GETDATE() (I don't need the precision from SYSDATETIME() anyway) speeds things up:

```
select [....]
where dateinquestion >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())
```

Results are similar to scenario 1.

I believe this is because SYSDATETIME is evaluated on a per-row-basis because processing a row costs several nanoseconds, significant to SYSDATETIME. GETDATE however, having a higher change-threshold, is unaffected (or less affected) and does not change - or need re-evaluating - on a per-row-basis.

Can you confirm? Is my assumption concerning this behaviour correct?

I've searched for this, but couldn't find anything except this, which only concerns assigning SYSDATETIME() to a variable, not using it in a WHERE:
[Does SYSDATETIME() cost more than GETDATE()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856438/does-sysdatetime-cost-more-than-getdate)

Also this, but only GETDATE is used in the example:
[TSQL datetimes functions in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927096/tsql-datetimes-functions-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most important difference between `GETDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` is the type of the returned value. `SYSDATETIME` is not evaluated for each row, same as `GETDATE` is not evaluated for each row. They are [Runtime Constant Functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/does-sql-server-evaluate-functions-once-for-every-row

What is the type of `dateinquestion` column?

When you used a `@startdate` variable you converted the result of `SYSDATETIME` to `date`. When you don't use a variable, the result of `DATEADD` has different types in your examples.

To make both queries with `GETDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` equivalent you can cast to `date` explicitly:

Compare

```
select [....]
where dateinquestion >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, SYSDATETIME()) AS date)
```

vs

```
select [....]
where dateinquestion >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) as date)
```

I'd be surprised if these two queries ran differently.

Ideally you should cast them to the same type that `dateinquestion` has.

You said that variant with `SYSDATETIME` uses a lot of CPU. If `dateinquestion` has type `datetime`, then a possible explanation could be this. It seems that in this variant the values from `dateinquestion` column are implicitly converted to `datetime2(7)` type before comparison. For each row. First, it uses CPU. Second, it may prevent optimizer from using an index on this column (if there is an index).

To see what is really going on, rather than guessing, compare the actual execution plan of both variants.

By the way, the variant with variable is not equivalent to inlined variant for the optimizer. Optimizer doesn't know the value of the variable, but it knows the value of the `GETDATE()` and `SYSDATETIME()`, so cardinality estimations are different, which can lead to different plans and different performance.

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned type precedence. But that is actually the answer to your question. The fact is that `SYSDATETIME` returns type `datetime2(7)` and `GETDATE` returns type `datetime`. And if you look at type precedence table(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) you will see that `datetime2(7)` precedes `datetime`. This means that:

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence.

So actually every row in a table is converted to `datetime2(7)`. That's why it is slow. If precedence was the other way round, your variable would be converted and not every row in a table.

Comment: The conversion is not the only reason for being slow. Due to the conversion, the database cannot use the index on the `datetime` field anymore, and needs to do slow table scans instead.

Answer (score 2):

Definition by Microsoft:

- `SYSDATETIME` returns a **`datetime2(7)`** value
- `GETDATE` returns a **`datetime`** value

If your field `dateinquestion` is of type `datetime`, then there will be a cast between `datetime` and `datetime2` in every row (since every row needs to be compared), and therefore, the execution is slower. Also, as it was already stated in an other answer, due to the cast, an index can possibly not be used.